# javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'message' for locale 'en_US'

Tags: spring, jsp, properties

I am reading property file using @ProprtySource below is my code-

```
@PropertySource(value="classpath:/application.properties")
public class HomeService{
    @Value("${message}")
    String message;
}
```

Also in my JSP-

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<spring:eval expression="@environment.getProperty('message')" />
```

Both are working fine.

**Note:** I have not registered any `propertySourcePlaceHolderConfigurer` or `ResourceBundle`ie no other configuration apart from above.

But As soon as I applied `spring:message` as-

```
<spring:message code="message"/>
```

this giving me exception-

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'message' for locale 'en_US'.

Answer (score 1):

The spring:message tag provides you with internationalization support using Spring's MessageSource concept. The MessageSource is an interface providing functionality for retrieving messages. You need to configure a ResourceBundleMessageSource to be able to make use of spring:message-tag.

```
<bean id="messageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="messages"/>
</bean>
```

Or by java configuration:

```
    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

Comment: You have saved my weekend! Thank you :-)